# Is it appropriate to add new files manually to project created with angular-cli

Tags: angular-cli

I have a project created using angular-cli. Is it appropriate to add the new files manually? Means not using angular-cli to generates the files. Will it cause a problem later? Angular-cli experts, need your helps to clarify on this. Much thanks.

Comment: No it wont cause a problem it is meant to be always added , cli just adds the required wire frame skeleton to a Angular project and you need to build up on top of that for your project

Comment: Thanks @RahulSingh.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to add your own source files (classes, templates, stylesheets etc.) manually. For third party libraries it's recommended to use NPM and not add them manually.